# Nesting lists based on the value

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that include some name, values and integer indicating depth of nesting. Nesting can theoretically go infinitely, Realistically 5 levels. Looks something like this:

```
[['TopValue1', 3453, 0],['TopValue2', 53453, 0],['LowerValue1', '', 1],['EvenLowerValue1', 34534, 2],['EvenLowerValue2', 6343, 2],['LowerValue2', '', 1],['EvenLowerValue1', '', 2],['CanEvenGoLower1', 42365, 3],['TopValue3', 3463, 0]]
```

For readability:

```
[
    ['TopValue1', 3453, 0],
    ['TopValue2', '', 0],
        ['LowerValue1', '', 1],
            ['EvenLowerValue1', 34534, 2],
            ['EvenLowerValue2', 6343, 2],
        ['LowerValue2', '', 1],
            ['EvenLowerValue1', '', 2],
                ['CanEvenGoLower1', 42365, 3],
    ['TopValue3', 3463, 0]
]
```

Is there a way to sort it in the way that would provide structure like this? Lack of values in 'top' elements is intentional, they are getting replaced by lists from 'lower' levels.

```
[['TopValue1', 3453],['TopValue2', [['LowerValue1', [['EvenLowerValue1', 34534],['EvenLowerValue2', 6343]]],['LowerValue2', ['EvenLowerValue1', ['CanEvenGoLower1', 42365]]]]],['TopValue3', 3463]]
```

For readability:

```
[
    ['TopValue1', 3453],
    ['TopValue2', 
        [['LowerValue1', 
            [['EvenLowerValue1', 34534],
            ['EvenLowerValue2', 6343]]],
        ['LowerValue2', 
            ['EvenLowerValue1', 
                ['CanEvenGoLower1', 42365]]]]],
    ['TopValue3', 3463]
]
```

I tried this atrocity but it's getting me nowhere

```
parsedData = [['TopValue1', 3453, 0],['TopValue2', 53453, 0],['LowerValue1', '', 1],['EvenLowerValue1', 34534, 2],['EvenLowerValue2', 6343, 2],['LowerValue2', '', 1],['EvenLowerValue1', '', 2],['CanEvenGoLower1', 42365, 3],['TopValue3', 3463, 0]]
for index, i in enumerate(parsedData):
    if index < len(parsedData)-1:
        if i[2] == 0 and index == 0: #case of first item
            collapsedList.append(i)
            collapsedList[index].pop(2)
        elif i[2] == 0 and parsedData[index+1][2] == 0:
            collapsedList.append(i)
            collapsedList[index].pop(2)
        elif i[2] <= parsedData[index+1][2]:
            collapsedList.append(i)
            print(collapsedList)
            if i[2] == parsedData[index+1][2]:
                collapsedList[index-1].insert(1,i)
            elif i[2] > parsedData[index+1][2]:
                collapsedList[index-1].insert(1,i)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Are you using the *same* `value` everywhere? If not, then please provide the input in valid Python syntax, because now `value` is a **name**, and also `TopLevel1` is a name. I have a hunch you actually don't have those names, but have **strings**. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, your input has 9 occurrences of `value`, and your output has 5 occurrences. Is it intended that you throw away 4 values?

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll edit it in a minute

Comment: I'm trying to fix it and be as clear as possible, sorry for messing with the edits on the fly.
You're right, rookie's mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a stack. If the level *decreases*, then clip the stack to correspond to that level, and when the level increases (with 1), then append a pair to that stack. Some extra logic is needed to replace the second member of a pair with a new list if it is not a leaf node:

```
def make_hierarchy(parsedData):
    root = []
    stack = [["", root]]
    for value1, value2, level in parsedData:
        stack[level+1:] = []  # clip the stack
        if type(stack[-1][1]) is not list:
            stack[-1][1] = []  # replace second value with new list
        stack[-1][1].append([value1, value2])  # inject pair
        stack.append(stack[-1][1][-1])  # ...and also stack this pair
    return root
```

Comment: Thank you , that is working like a charm. Now if you'll excuse me I'll study it religiously so I can wrap my head around it :)